# Getting the next node of a node that contains a node with some value

Tags: xpath

I'm trying to parse my Facebook message history because I'm interested in who uses which words how often and stuff like that.

This is the structure of nodes that represents a conversation between two people (Mary and John):

```
<div class="thread">

Mary Smith, John Smith

<div class="message">
    <div class="message_header">
        <span class="user">Mary Smith</span>
        <span class="meta">Saturday, October 12, 2013 at 12:53am UTC+02</span>
    </div>
</div>
<p>Hello, how are you?</p>

<div class="message">
    div class="message_header">
        <span class="user">John Smith</span>
        <span class="meta">Saturday, October 12, 2013 at 12:55am UTC+02</span>
    </div>
</div>
<p>I am fine, thank you for asking.</p>

</div>
```

I want to fetch all messages whose author is Mary (using XPath). I can recognize that something is a message written by Mary because it's in a `p` after a `div` of class `message` which has a child `div` of class `message_header` which has a `span` child of class `user` whose content contains "Mary".

My attempt:

```
//div[@class="thread"]/p[preceding-sibling::div[@class="message"][div[@class="message_header"][span[@class="user"][contains(., "Mary")]]]]
```

This may or may not be correct, but it's unusable because it's too slow.
Is there a smarter way to write this query?

Oh and, I'm using Ruby + Nokogiri to parse the document, but I'm not sure if that's relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**With a more flexible structure**

Something like

```
//div[.//text()="Mary Smith"]/following-sibling::p[1]
```

would certainly shorten your xpath. Unfortunately I don't know much about the speed of processing, but I guess less tests means faster execution. If there are a lot of text fields between nodes, and not a lot of `span` it may be quicker to do

```
//div[.//span[@class="user"]/text()="Mary Smith"]/following-sibling::p[1]
```

Let me know if this improves the speed significantly!

**With a rigid structure**

If the structure is fixed as you showed, it may be quicker to use fixed path and avoid `//` as much as possible:

```
//div[div/span/text()="Mary Smith"]/following-sibling::p[1]
```